# How to change orientation to portrait in Fragment Class - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

My application is in Landscape mode .. I'm trying to change the Fragment in Portrait view ..

Used the below code to rotate from landscape to portrait ..

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

But the Fragment "onCreate" and "onCreateView" called twice ..

Can anyone please advice on implement Portrait View in Fragment class ? Or advice to how to avoid calling the onCreateView twice ?

Comment: Where did you place the above code?

Comment: take a look on setRatainInstance(boolean) method

Comment: show us some more code please, specifically of your Fragment or Class.

Comment: @Eenvincible in onCreateView i placed the code snippet ..

Comment: @janpan Here's my Fragment : http://pastebin.com/JiuubGju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Manifest file your activity should adds,

> "android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

For example,

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Specifically you should add "screenSize" in the Android manifest file. So that your Fragment "onCreate" and "onCreateView" won't be called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Override setRetainInstance. This should solve your problem

Comment: Can you please paste the code snipped to check ? Because i have been setRetainInstance(true) in onCreate method ..